# Ошибка при вводе кода SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame  
   pygame.init()
   win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
   pygame.display.set_caption("Cubes Game")
   x = 50
   y = 50
   widht = 40
   height = 60
   speed = 5

   run = True
   while run:
      pygame.time.delay(100)
      for event in pygame.event.get():
          if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
              run = False
      pygame.draw.rect(win, (0,0,255),(x,y,widht, height))
      pygame.display.update()

    pygame.quit()
```

Comment: первая строка import pygame выводится при одиночном запуске без ошибки

Comment: Полный текст ошибки добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement   - Текст ошибки

Comment: Ошибки в Python никогда не бывают в одну строку, минимум - три. Причём ответ как раз в тех строках, которые вы не показываете.

Comment: [скриншот](http://skrinshoter.ru/s/230519/MupESCZV?a)

Comment: Это откуда скриншот? Какой-то REPL или IDE?

Comment: Это Python IDLE

Comment: И этот код вы вставили одним куском из буфера обмена?

Comment: да, из буфера обмена

Comment: В IDLE это не сработает, она посчитает все вставляемые строчки одной инструкцией. Либо вставляйте\вводите построчно, либо используйте более умную среду\консоль.

Comment: Syntax Error обычно означает проблемы с синтаксисом. Дважды проверьте все отступы на правильность.